# Redirect all webpages under webroot to login page in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.4.5. I would like to redirect all users who have not logged in to a login page. I basically followed the instructions available [here](http://miftyisbored.com/a-complete-login-and-authentication-application-tutorial-for-cakephp-2-3/).

In summary, the important part is the following code to AppController.php

```
public $components = array('Session',
                            'Auth' => array(
                                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
                                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                                'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
                                'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.'        
                            ));
```

Any websites with this URL format `http://localhost/cakephp245/controllers/XXX` will be re-directed to the login page. However, websites that are located inside `app/webroot` with URL that looks like this  `http://localhost/cakephp245/app/webroot/XXX` will not be re-directed to the login page.

How can I force websites located inside app/webroot folder to be re-directed to the login page?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Websites located inside webroot? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the steps that can help to resolve the issues :-

1) Read the documentation how to load the auth componenet in appController
   https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html
Code should be like the below code

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'loginAction' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login',
                    'plugin' => null
                ],
                //'authorize' => ['Controller'],
                'loginRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'dashboard'
                ],
                'logoutRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login',
                ],
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => ['username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']
                    ]
                ],
                'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
                'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
                'storage' => 'Session'
            ]);
```

2) Add below code to beforeFilter() of usersController

```
$this->Auth->allow(['login','logout','register']);  // these function will be pulic access
```

3) Here is the login function put it in UserController

```
 public function login()
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('adminlogin'); // set the admin login layout 

        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        $this->set('user', $user);

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user){
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));         
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to the AppController.

```
public function beforeFilter() {        
    $this->Auth->deny();        
    $this->Auth->allow('login');
}
```

This way, the only action allowed before login is login itself.
Still, this won't make images or scripts or css unavailable, if that's what you're aiming for.

Though I'm not completely certain, I believe there is no way to deny someone access to this type of resources.